# Idea Community with Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, plugins, intellij-idea

I've started working with Spring Framework and InteliJ Idea lately, but when I wanted to launch a Tomcat server for code deployment I saw it is not available in Community Edition. Is it not available to use in Idea? If so, are there any alternatives for this, because I don't like Eclipse at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the community edition, you can run maven from the command line or as a maven run configuration (or mvnDebug for debugging from the command line), and then attach a remote debug session.

This is a minimal configuration for the maven tomcat plugin, see here for the full [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NetBeans if you don't like eclipse. Otherwise you can run tomcat externally and do the deployment, testing manually.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can configure to remote debug from IDEA the application installed in tomcat.  Step by step instructions are provided in the document (
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2s6j6hxpukgskwo/SetupTomcatInIdeaCommunity.pdf?dl=0)